# CocoaPods with Xcode 10 RuntimeError Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes

Tags: cocoapods, xcode10

I'm trying to install a pod with `pod install` and getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError - [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.
```

I'm using CocoaPods 1.5.3 and Xcode 10.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a known bug introduced by Xcode 10 which fixed in CocoaPods 1.6.0. Right now (Jan 2019) it's in beta, so you can install it with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Alternative solution for CocoaPods 1.5.3 could be found [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7835#issuecomment-407428465).

Comment: This worked for me (using beta version of cocoa pods). Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This will surely work, It worked for me. cheers!!!

You have to remove following from your from the **project.pbxproj** file.

[image]

Remove following

```
  inputFileListPaths = (

  );


  outputFileListPaths = (

  );
```

Comment: Great, work for me without install pre version. you save my day

Answer (score 2):

...also, for the solution provided by @Purnendu roy, here's how to access the aforementioned project.pbxproj file. (right-clicking on the .xcodeproj file)
[image: (right click on your .xcodeproj file]

Answer (score 2):

`gem update xcodeproj` worked for me, thanks to this post http://swiftdynamics.blogspot.com/2019/01/pod-install-issue-xcodeproj-doesnt-know_29.html